# How to pass function as a prop in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am learning typescript with react and I occurred problem. I tried to pass function as a prop from my App component to child component named DataForm.

but I got an error:

> Type '(f: any) => any' is not assignable to type '() => void'. 
> Parameter 'f' implicitly has an 'any' type.

And this is my code

App.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import DataForm from './components/form';

export const Data = {
  name: "",
  country: "",
  age:"",
  adress:""
}

function App() {


  const generateCard = ()=>{
    console.log(" generateCard runned")
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Human Card Generator</h1>
      <DataForm  createCard = { generateCard }/>
    </>
    

  );
}

export default App;
```

components/form.tsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Data } from '../App'
import 'bootstrap';

interface dataFormProps{
    createCard: ()=>void
}

export default function DataForm({ createCard = f => f }: dataFormProps){

    const dataProceed = (e: any) =>{
        Data.name = (document.getElementById('name') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        Data.country = (document.getElementById('country') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        Data.age = (document.getElementById('age') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        Data.adress = (document.getElementById('adress') as HTMLInputElement).value;
        createCard();
    }


    return(
        <form onSubmit = { dataProceed }>
            <input type="text"   id = "name"  />
            <input type="text"  id = "country" />
            <input type="number" id="age" />
            <input type="text" id = "adress"/>
            <button type="submit">stwórz kartę</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: `dataFormProps` explicitly doesn't match your default function--you have to decide on a function signature, regardless of what it is, and make both explicitly-passed and default functions match that signature.

Comment: Well you defined createCard as ()=>void but then you default it to f => f.   So the default value for createCard does not match () => void

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue isn't when passing the function, it's when destructuring the props and providing a default function:

```
{ createCard = f => f }: dataFormProps
```

This code indicates that `createCard` should be a function which accepts a parameter and returns a value.  Which it doesn't:

```
createCard: ()=>void
```

Make the default parameter match the signature:

```
{ createCard = () => {} }: dataFormProps
```

Answer (score 4):

default function `createCard` should has type `() => void`. So just update like this:

```
DataForm({ createCard = () => {} }: dataFormProps)
```